# Problema al hacer referencia a un miembro estático de tipo string

Tags: c++, class

tengo la siguiente clase

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct structMenu
{
    int index;
    string option;
    void (*functionOption)();
    structMenu *next;
    structMenu *previous;
};

class Menu
{
private:
    int indexMenu;
    static string value_;
    structMenu* Head;
    structMenu* Tail;
public:
    Menu();
    static string getTitle()
    {
        return value_;
    }
    static void setTitle(string dataTitle)
    {
         value_ = dataTitle;
    }
    void addNewOption(string nameOption, void (*functionOption)());
    static void printMenu(Menu thisMenu);
    static void spc(int space);
    static void jump(int nJump);


};
```

y obtengo el siguiente error
**undefined reference to `Menu::value_[abi:cxx11]'|**

apareciendo el error en los metodos en los que se hace referencia a este valor

```
static string getTitle()
    {
        return value_;
    }
    static void setTitle(string dataTitle)
    {
         value_ = dataTitle;
    }
```

Sinceramente no entiendo la naturaleza del error probé realizando el cambio directamente colocando el atributo como publico

```
public:
    static string value_;
```

y hago referencia a este fuera del programa como
`Menu::value_`
Pero obtengo el mismo error, agradezco mucho la ayuda, y gracias de antemano.

```
El error posiblemente este en la forma de declarar value_
...
private:
    int indexMenu;
    static string value_;
...
```

Comment: ¿ Puedes mostrar cómo le asignas el valor inicial ?

Comment: Si, perdon no aclare eso en el codigo, pero se hace a través del los metodos setter y getter para ese atributo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las variables *estáticas* (`static`) tienen una particularidad: **necesitan ser inicializadas**, **no** es suficiente solo con declararlas. Y, además, esa inicialización **ha de hacerse de forma separada** (hay excepciones, pero las dejaremos fuera para no extendernos).

Es una simple inicialización *corriente* y *moliente*:

```
string Menu::value_ = std::string( );
```

Salvo que estés en C++17 y superior, es importante hacer esto **solo una vez**; en otras palabras, **no se puede hacer en un archivo de cabecera**.

Si estás en C++17 o superior, puedes hacerlo en el propio archivo de cabecera, siempre y cuando indiques explicitamente el hecho de que la declaración puede repetirse:

```
class Menu {
  ...
};

inline string Menu::value_ = string( );
```

Comment: Estoy 100% seguro de que esta pregunta está duplicada, pero no la encuentro. Por favor, si alguien la encuentra, que la marque como tal.

Comment: Me ha funcionado pero agregando directamente: std::string Menu::value_ = "";   por alguna razón no me funciono igualando a std::string

Comment: Por una razón muy concreta: está mal, es `string Menu::vlaue_ = string( );`. Lo siento, se me *escaparon* los paréntesis. Edito y corrijo.